# Append child can`t add more than 1 child node

Tags: javascript

```
var data={
    1:"dasf",
    2:"jlla",
    3:"jalf"
};
(function () {
    var table=document.createElement("table");
    var tr=document.createElement("tr");
    for(var i in data){
        tr.innerText=data[i];
        (function(){
             table.appendChild(tr);
              console.log("in"+tr.innerText)
         })();
        console.log("out"+table);
    }
})();
```

it always shows different and changes everytime,guessing the time appendchild happenes is not simply following?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only **create** one `tr` element.

Each time you append it, you move it from where it was in the DOM and put it in the new location.

If you want to create a new table row for each item in `data`, then you need to move your `createElement` call **inside the loop**.

(You also need to change how you are adding content to it, a tr element isn't allowed to contain text directly, and if you aren't putting *multiple* data cells in each row, you should probably be using a list instead of a table in the first place).

Comment: Might be worth mentioning insertRow() too 

Answer (score 0):

See this snippet code for creating table
I have edited your code

```html
<div id="wrap"></div>

<script>

var data={
    1:"dasf",
    2:"jlla",
    3:"jalf"
};
(function () {
    var table=document.createElement("table");
    var tr;
    var td;
    for(var i in data){
        tr=document.createElement("tr");
        td=document.createElement("td");
        td.innerText = data[i];

        tr.appendChild(td);
        table.appendChild(tr);
    }
 
document.getElementById("wrap").appendChild(table)
})();

</script>
```

This will be the output table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>dasf</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>jlla</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>jalf</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```